# Infer the type of a field without generic type arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a type called `Component`. It has a generic parameter called `Props`, that needs to implement `Record<string, any>`. What I need is to create a type, that receives a component in one property, and also has to implement a function that returns `Props` for the component. I will store these objects in a dictionary  like this:

```js
const components: Record<string, ComponentConfig> = {
  someKey: {
    component: Component1, // Implements the type of Component<{num: number}>,
    props() { // Props should be strongly typed
      return {
        num: 1
      }
    }
  },
  someOtherKey: {
    component: Component2, // Implements the type of Component<{str: string}>,
    props() { // Props should be strongly typed
      return {
        str: "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I tried is this solution:

```js
type ComponentConfig = never extends infer Props
  ? Props extends Record<string, any>
    ? {
        component: Component<Props>
        props(): Props
      }
    : string // originally never, modified for this example
  : never
```

However this leads to an error, when assinging an object to a key of the dictionary:

```js
// TS2322: Type { component: Component<{ num: number; }>; props(): { num: number; }; } is not assignable to type  never 
const cfg: Record<string, ComponentConfig> = {
    someKey: {
        component: component1,
        props() {
            return {
                num: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand why though. Never seems to be extending everything. Which is kinda logical becuase the empty set is the subset of every set. So the first ternary expression should evaluate true, always. Which means that depending on the type of `Props` the resolved type should either be `{component: Component<Props>; props(): Props}` or `string`. But I get `never` which I do not really understand.

I do these shenanigans so that I can introduce this new type variable `Props`. So if there are more elegant ways to do this, I am open to those.

My first thought was to get it as a generic argument, but that would not work, since I would need to pass it when I'm creating the `cfg` Record. If I pass any/unknown, then the typings would be incorrect for the props function. What I basically want is to infer the gerenic argument of the `component` property, and use it as a return type in the `props` function.

Comment: `never` checs MUST have `[never] extends [T]` (or `[T] extends [never]` I don't remember) wrappings, otherwise it drops to `T in never` leading to result of just `never`

Comment: Could you show where I should place the []-s? If I change it to [never] extends infer [Props], then it doesn't even recognize that Props is a type variable. Also `const a: never extends Record<string, any> ? 'yes' : 'no' = 'yes'` compiles correctly, so I'm not sure if the never check is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of a tricky topic regarding [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Essentially you'll have to do is wrap your condition in `[]` in order to to actually be true.

```
type ComponentConfig = never extends infer Props
  ? [Props] extends [Record<string, any>]
    ? {
        component: Component<Props>
        props(): Props
      }
    : never
  : never
```

If we break it down you can see that `never` in a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) behaves like it isn't there at all.

```
type Result = string | number | never; // string | number
type Result2 = string | never; // string
type Result3 = never; // now it is never
```

Now if you type conditions which resolve to `never` (=empty union) it always returns another empty union which is `never`. If we wrap `never` in array brackets (`[]`) we can keep that value in our union.

```
type Result4 = string | [never]; // string | [never];
```

---

Alright, but now we're having trouble with the actual typings of the component because the generic argument `T` of `Component<T>` will resolve to `never`. To fix that pass the Props as a generic to your `ComponenConfig<Props>`. I don't really see the point of the `infer` here tbh.

```
type Component<Props extends Record<string, any>> = {
  props: Props;
};

type ComponentConfig<Props> = never extends Props
  ? [Props] extends [Record<string, any>]
    ? {
        component: Component<Props>;
        props(): Props;
      }
    : never
  : never;

const cfg: Record<string, ComponentConfig<{prop1: number}>> = {
  someKey: {
    component: {props: {prop1: 0}},
    props() {
      return {
        prop1: 1
      };
    }
  }
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwA8AFATnMAZyggA9h0ATYgJQgGM5dLNDhcBLFAcwBooAhihAA%20EVAC8UAN4BYAFBQoYfEQBcUPAUIBuBQF898haEixEyNBngoAZh245VhcVLQA3CLhLkqxLUQKSgD8UADaAYQAuj4UKNThdIzMrOxcfILCIlFBSlChcop5xYxIqOjAGvBlVliRIkbFxSraABQAlBqRjU36uUoabJw8uRoeXkYKjChsUPS23BpJTCxD6fzVlhU29o7SLWAAjGMArggARl76YpIyuYSIEADSECAahSUW5RjvB4S-qmOUAADPp9Lx%20spnB07kVirgIMATrgULCmnkDkDDpClIZIX0igS8cZ5KZoHRCCcADbAW5rHhQAA%20UBQZ0u3mZ41wOigAHpeVB6dwmSy2V4TOByRBKTSAEx0tIMzkQTzcvkCoUSswU6nAADMty5PP5LLgAHcoBxaRxiFytVKZcAACwK4bC5lhLlRY0axXu8JenRAA)

Comment: By specifying the type of `cfg` as `Record<string, ComponentConfig<{prop1: number}>>`, now it only accepts components that have a `prop1: number` property. What I want is for this dictionary to accept multiple kinds of components with different props types, and for each component, define a function that returns the type of the component's prop. I'm beginning to question if it is possible tho. This is why I did the whole infer thing in the first place.